# JavaScript variable not storing wordpress child theme path

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

```
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory(); ?>";
```

where get_stylesheet_directory() = D:\Copy\wamp\www

```
console.log(ajaxurl);
```

which is showing D:Copywampwww

I don't know why "/" are removing while storing variable

even if try

```
var ajaxurl = "D:\Copy\wamp\www";
```

it showing "D:Copywampwww"

only var ajaxurl = "D:\Copy\wamp\www"; will work , but anyone can help

```
"D:\Copy\wamp\www"="D:\\Copy\\wamp\\www"
```

in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape characters.

You need to escape `\` in your string.

In order to do that in php you can use `echo json_encode(get_stylesheet_directory());`